# nginx issues 404 errors. The file can be access from the browser no problems. ununderstable.

Tags: nginx

I have a simple nginx setup. When i try to go to the `localhost` from the browser, i get a 404 error.

Here my nginx config file:

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        ssi on;
        location / {
            index /srv/http/city_db/static/index.html;
            ssi on;
        }
    }
}
```

If I simple type in the url-bar in the browser `/srv/http/city_db/static/index.html`
it instanteneously takes me to the file and all works normally.

And, also I did `systemctl restart nginx` ofcourse.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) to `/srv/http/city_db/static/` and [`index`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) to `index.html`. For this configuration you do not need the `location` block, you can set both at the `server` level.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    ssi on;
    root /srv/http/city_db/static/;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        # other things you want to set for /
    }
}
```